# Read Information for incoming slack webhooks via api

Tags: slack, slack-api

Following the steps for creating incoming webhooks via [add to slack button](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button#). The final response will look like this:

```
{
"access_token": "xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
"scope": "incoming-webhook,commands,bot",
"team_name": "Team Installing Your Hook",
"team_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
"incoming_webhook": {
    "url": "https://hooks.slack.com/TXXXXX/BXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX",
    "channel": "#channel-it-will-post-to",
    "configuration_url": "https://teamname.slack.com/services/BXXXXX"
},
    ....
}
```

This provides access to team_name, channel the webhook will post to, and a url for configuration.

While this is working great and after initially storing the 'configuration' to my own webapp it displays correctly. But after a someone uses the 'configuration_url' link from the response these previous values like the channel could become obsolete. For example the webhook could be deleted from this link.

**My Question is:
Is there a way to reflect this changes in my external app? As far as I can see there is no way to query information for 'incoming webhooks' via an api call from an external web application?**

I also could not find any api calls that could change webhook configuration directly without using the provided link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to change the webhook configuration after it is created. The only possible change is that the workspace that installed your Slack app (which contains the webhook) is uninstalled.

If that happens the webhook will no longer work and you will get an error in response.

You can also get notified when you app is uninstalled by listening to the [`app_uninstalled`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_uninstalled) event.

Or you can also test if your app and webhook is still valid by checking the token you received during the Add to Slack process. Just call the API method [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) with that token. If it returns the following error than the webhook is no longer valid:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_auth"
}
```